# using imageresizer in another orchard module not working

Tags: module, namespaces, orchardcms, image-resizing

I want to use the [Image Resizer Module](https://github.com/pnmcosta/orchardcontribthumbnails)
in the `Nwazet.ZenGallery Module` (`ZenGallery.cshtml`).

But somehow, it's not working. When I use the `@Html.Thumnail(...)` inside a view in my theme, it works, but not in the view from the ZenGallery module. Why?

It says `The type or namespace name 'Contrib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

How could I fix that?

Comment: i guess it's because the contrib.thumbnails is not built before the zengallery module?

Comment: I guess it's because you didn't add a reference to the csproj...

Comment: Thanks, you are the man to ask as always :)
btw great module (ZenGallery)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net) directly instead of using [Orchard Contrib.Thumbnails](https://github.com/pnmcosta/orchardcontribthumbnails).

Contrib.Thumbnails violates [ImageResizer best practices](http://imageresizing.net/docs/best-practices) and takes an approach that has known stability issues.

There's also no need for Contrib.Thumbnails; ImageResizer already offers [a URL API you can use directly](http://imageresizing.net/docs/basics), with better performance, stability, and a much cleaner syntax.